# Azure B2C UserInput accept email or phone number

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, azure-ad-b2c

We have a username and password page that we need to be able to accept email address or phone numbers.

I have this working, HOWEVER the phone number requires the +1 country code.

The issue I have is that all our customers are US based so we do not need the +1. I have tried to regex the input, but nothing I do seems to work.

Our customers will not be entering +1 they will be doing things like xxxxxxxxxx.

I have built a regex to remove the +1 but it does not seem to be working.

Here is a copy of what I am doing.

```
<!-- Main Sign in -->
    <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="EnforceEmailVerification">False</Item>
        <Item Key="setting.showSignupLink">false</Item>
        <Item Key="setting.enableRememberMe">True</Item>
        <Item Key="setting.forgotPasswordLinkOverride">ForgotPasswordExchange</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <InputClaimsTransformations>
        <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="AddCountryCode" />
      </InputClaimsTransformations>

      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_lastLogon" />
      </OutputClaims>

      <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="Get-additional-claims" ContinueOnError="false" />
        <!-- Initiate a normal logon against Azure AD B2C -->
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="login-NonInteractive" />
      </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>

      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

and the transformation

```
     <ClaimsTransformation Id="AddCountryCode" TransformationMethod="FormatStringClaim">
        <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
        </InputClaims>
        <InputParameters>
        <InputParameter Id="stringFormat" DataType="string" Value="+1{0}" />
        </InputParameters>
        <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="PhoneWithCountryCode" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
        </OutputClaims>
    </ClaimsTransformation>
```

Comment: You want the +1 to be added by code or do you not need that at all?

Comment: @kavyaS i need the country code added automatically through a claims transformation. our customers are not going to type a country code in since we have all US based customers.

Answer (score 0):

Note sure what phone code you are using but have a look at this [sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/signup-signin-with-phone-number).

Usually, the countryCode and nationalNumber are two different fields and then concatenated together.

Then:

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="CombineCountryCodeAndNationalNumber">
    <DisplayName>Combine country code and national number</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
    <InputClaimsTransformations>
        <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="ConvertStringToPhoneNumber"/>
    </InputClaimsTransformations>
    <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.phoneNumber"/>
    </OutputClaims>
    <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop"/>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Comment: Yes, I understand this. But all our users are US based. We have geoblock in place. and our customers are not going to understanding using a country code / national number. Its just not practical. I have a SignInName claim, which will accept both an email and phone number, however the phone number has to have the country code in front of it. There just does not seem to be a way to do it WITH an an email and if the CC was being appended in.